# Add IF ELSE statment

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have function in PHP something like,

```
if (  $busyUsersIDS ) {
 SELECT statment 
ELSE {
SELECT statment
 }
```

SO far I translate this to function in Oracle SQL and the main problem now is add `IF ELSE` which is for me like beginner a pretty hard, whatever I try I always get error

```
FUNCTION GET_MOMENT_PROJECT_USERS(p_busyUsersID IN INT)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    /*getBusyUsersIDS*/
 BEGIN
  OPEN rc FOR
    CASE bussyUserID WHEN bussyUserID THEN
        SELECT u.*,
                ur.Roles 
        FROM 
                users u 
        INNER JOIN 
                user_roles ur 
        ON 
                u.User_roleID = ur.id 
        WHERE 
                u.UserID NOT IN (p_busyUsersID) 
        AND 
                u.Surname IS NOT NULL
        AND 
                u.Lastname IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY
                u.ProjectPlanSortIndex;

        ELSE  
                            
        SELECT  u.*, 
                ur.Roles 
        FROM 
                users u 
        INNER JOIN 
                user_roles ur 
        ON 
                u.User_roleID = ur.id 
        WHERE 
                u.Surname IS NOT NULL 
        AND 
                u.Lastname IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY 
                u.ProjectPlanSortIndex;
     END;
  RETURN rc;
END GET_BUSY_USERS_IDS;
```

So far there are two error which I get

> Error(524,9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date       pipe        <an alternat

> Error(528,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INNER" when expecting one of the following:     , ; for group having intersect minus order start union where    connect

Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake and what is wrong here?

Comment: You are abusing the `open for` syntax. I would rather write something like `case when busyuserid = someid then open rc for select ...; when busyuserid = otherid then open cursor for otherselect; else open rc for anotherselect; end case;`

Comment: I don't want always OPEN rc FOR only once at the begginer. 
So somethinig like this `OPEN rc FOR IF  condition THEN {SELECT} ELSE {SELECT}`

Comment: This whole design looks flawed. You have busyUsersIDS, which implies that you can have more than one, however you pass just one with the INT input type. Do you have the busy users in some table, it's always better to just join that table instead of creating function which would implement the logic of a join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding how to cope with this kind of syntax issue as a beginner, I suggest that you practice simplifying it down to the smallest example possible, so that you are not distracted by the join logic.

For example, you can quickly test this and see that it **won't work**:

```
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for
        case
            when 1 = 1 then select * from dual  -- not valid
        end;
end;
```

which fails with

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 29:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: ...
```

because the `open rc for select` syntax has to be a single statement and can't be split up with conditional logic.

Notice how there is no `create function`, parameters or joins etc to complicate things. You can add all of those back in once you've got the syntax straightened out. The `case` statement syntax is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-3937FEB2-96A1-456B-AD9E-09B627DF0939). (Notice that there are a couple of different kinds of `case`.) It needs to be either

```
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    case
        when 1 = 1 then
            open rc for select * from dual;
    end case;
end;
```

or the equivalent using `if`:

```
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    if 1 = 1 then
        open rc for select * from dual;
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid syntax.  You can do this (as Florin Ghita suggested in a comment):

```
FUNCTION GET_MOMENT_PROJECT_USERS(p_busyUsersID IN INT)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    /*getBusyUsersIDS*/
 BEGIN
  CASE bussyUserID WHEN bussyUserID THEN
    OPEN rc FOR
        SELECT u.*,
                ur.Roles 
        FROM 
                users u 
        INNER JOIN 
                user_roles ur 
        ON 
                u.User_roleID = ur.id 
        WHERE 
                u.UserID NOT IN (p_busyUsersID) 
        AND 
                u.Surname IS NOT NULL
        AND 
                u.Lastname IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY
                u.ProjectPlanSortIndex;

  ELSE  
     OPEN rc FOR
        SELECT  u.*, 
                ur.Roles 
        FROM 
                users u 
        INNER JOIN 
                user_roles ur 
        ON 
                u.User_roleID = ur.id 
        WHERE 
                u.Surname IS NOT NULL 
        AND 
                u.Lastname IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY 
                u.ProjectPlanSortIndex;
  END CASE;
  RETURN rc;
END GET_BUSY_USERS_IDS;
```

or you could move the condition into the WHERE clause of a single query something like:

```
FUNCTION GET_MOMENT_PROJECT_USERS(p_busyUsersID IN INT)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    /*getBusyUsersIDS*/
 BEGIN
  CASE bussyUserID WHEN bussyUserID THEN
    OPEN rc FOR
        SELECT u.*,
                ur.Roles 
        FROM 
                users u 
        INNER JOIN 
                user_roles ur 
        ON 
                u.User_roleID = ur.id 
        WHERE 
                (bussyUserID != bussyUserID
                 OR u.UserID NOT IN (p_busyUsersID))
        AND 
                u.Surname IS NOT NULL
        AND 
                u.Lastname IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY
                u.ProjectPlanSortIndex;

  END CASE;
  RETURN rc;
END GET_BUSY_USERS_IDS;
```

However, if either side of the condition `bussyUserID != bussyUserID` could be null then this would not work without some change to handle nulls.

(Note: Your condition doesn't make sense as you are comparing `bussyUserID` to itself!)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However I just realize this peace of code and I see that busyUserID can not be comapre with itself. However I  need to found some better soulution