# How can I modify query and add IF/ELSE in WHERE statment

Tags: oracle, plsql

I stuck in one problem and I have no idea how to solve it. So far I look  at a couple of post here but I can not find solution

[Post no 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63736125/add-if-else-statment)

I have query like this

```
SELECT 
     aa.Total
 FROM 
     ata_articles aa
 LEFT JOIN
     weekly_report wr
 ON
     aa.wrId = wr.id
 LEFT JOIN
     supplier_invoices si
 ON
     aa.SupplierInvoiceId = si.SupplierInvoicesID
 LEFT JOIN
     supplier_invoice_rows sir
 ON
     aa.SupplierInvoiceId = sir.id                    
 LEFT JOIN
     ata a
 ON
     a.ATAID = aa.AtaID
 WHERE 
     aa.AtaId = 1817
 AND 
     ((wr.status != 3 AND wr.status != 4) OR (aa.wrId = 0 AND a.PaymentType != 4))
 AND
  (IF (aa.TableType != 'Default', IF (si.Invoiced IS NULL, sir.Invoiced, si.Invoiced), NULL) = 1 OR aa.TableType = 'Default')
```

So far when I run this query I  get error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I try to change IF with CASE but still same error I get. I  try to add one more `bracket )` in the end but still have problem.
Can you please help me find the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use IF in SQL, it isn't part of the language. The permitted syntax is [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/). You seem to be trying to use constructs from another language or tool - looks like Excel? - rather than something Oracle will recognise.

You could do this with a case expression but it's not really appropriate here, and your logic can be simplified to:

```
AND
   (aa.TableType = 'Default' OR coalesce(si.Invoiced, sir.Invoiced) = 1)
```

You could use either [`coalesce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COALESCE.html) or [`nvl()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NVL.html), but coalesce is more flexible, and standard.

If `aa.TableType` can be null and you want to exclude those rows then you might need to add to this a little bit, but it doesn't look necessary.